# Telegram. Не приходит webhook по callback-кнопкам

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, webhook

Собственно, кратко проблема описана в заголовке.

Если более расширено, то webhook установлен, по нему приходят сообщения, написанные в бота.
Посмотрел логи сервера, запросов к адресу webhook'а в момент нажатия нет, ошибок тоже нет. При использовании метода /getWebhookInfo - ошибок нет, последний отправленный webhook это message.

Кнопка передается подобным массивом:

```
{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"\u041f\u043e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0431\u0430\u043b\u043b\u044b","callback_data":"getPoints"}]]}
```

Единственное, с чем это может быть связано(что нашел в интернете), с тем, что домен по ssllabs.com имеет рейтинг B, но тогда странно, что webhook приходит по сообщению в бота.

В интернете не удалось найти решение, может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что не смог зайти под этим пользователем(под которым писал вопрос).

Нашел решение для себя. При регистрации webhook'а для бота раньше я просто указывал ссылку на обработчик, то есть, общий запрос был вида:

```
* Preparing request to https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook
* Current time is 2021-04-03T20:25:23.173Z
* Using libcurl/7.73.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 WinIDN libssh2/1.9.0_DEV nghttp2/1.41.0
* Using default HTTP version
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 7 cookies
* Found bundle for host api.telegram.org: 0x293aad18c60 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host api.telegram.org
* Connected to api.telegram.org (149.154.167.220) port 443 (#0)

> POST /bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.telegram.org
> User-Agent: insomnia/2021.2.2
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 94

| {
|   "url": "https://example.com/api/"
| }
```

В этом случае, нажатие на callback-кнопку не приводило к отправке webhook'а

Затем я поменял немного запрос, передавая в него информацию о тех изменения, которые хочу получать в свой обработчик(массив "allowed_updates"), то есть запрос изменился на такой:

```
* Preparing request to https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook
* Current time is 2021-04-03T20:30:28.273Z
* Using libcurl/7.73.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 WinIDN libssh2/1.9.0_DEV nghttp2/1.41.0
* Using default HTTP version
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 7 cookies
* Found bundle for host api.telegram.org: 0x293aad18c60 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host api.telegram.org
* Connected to api.telegram.org (149.154.167.220) port 443 (#0)

> POST /bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.telegram.org
> User-Agent: insomnia/2021.2.2
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 94

| {
|   "url": "https://example.com/api/",
|   "allowed_updates": ["message","callback_query"]
| }
```

После передачи дополнительного параметра "allowed_updates", нажатие на callback-кнопку стало приходить в мой обработчик.

Дополнительно внесу комментарий, что в [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) по методу /setwebhook сказано, что при простой передаче url, webhook должен передаваться по всем событиям, кроме "chat_member", но видимо что-то поменялось, а в документации не отразили.